# What is the reason of syslog-ng error: "destination plugin http not found"?

Tags: syslog-ng

Here is part of my syslog-ng.conf file (with some exclusions):

```
destination d_elastic_docker {
    http(url("http://192.168.122.79:9200/_bulk")
        method("POST")
    );
};
```

I've got the following message from syslog-ng -v:

```
Error parsing destination, destination plugin http not found in /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/docker-journal-elastic.conf at line 31, column 5:
                                                  included from /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf line 162, column 1

    http(url("http://192.168.122.79:9200/_bulk")
    ^^^^
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http()` plugin is missing. Make sure you installed the appropriate package (for example, on [Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.syslog-ng.com/products/open-source-log-management/3rd-party-binaries.aspx): syslog-ng-mod-http), or use the `--enable-http` configure option if you compiled syslog-ng from source.

Comment: I've tried to install plugin with command: "sudo apt-get install syslog-ng-mod-http" on Ubuntu 18LTS, but the answer was: "Unable to locate package syslog-ng-mod-http"

Comment: What repository are you using? What's your syslog-ng version?

Comment: The syslog-ng-mod-http package is not available in the official ubuntu repo. You can install it from the unofficial repositories maintained by the developers, check https://www.syslog-ng.com/products/open-source-log-management/3rd-party-binaries.aspx